# What is the fraction of power transmitted to the generator in full-hybrid cars?

Tags: motors, energy-efficiency, propulsion, generator, car

In full-hybrid cars like the Toyota Prius, usually both internal combustion engine (ICE) and electric motor produces mechanical power to the wheels at cruise. But some of the mechanical power produced by the internal combustion engine is converted to electric power through a generator.

**I would like to know typical values for the fraction of the total power generated by the ICE, which is transmitted to the generator at cruise.**

Answer (score 1):

It will vary between 0 and maximum depending on the demands of the drive system - ie the engine output is shared whatever the wheels need and the remainder to the generator to charge the batteries.